# chrome extension youtube context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a solution to make youtube videos detect in context menus? A rightclick event and regex on page url I had in mind but I have no idea where to start. How could I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with the `manifest.json` file:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com","*://*.youtube.com/*"],
    "js": ["contextmenu.js"]
}]
...
```

And then with `contextmenu.js` file:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function(){ window.showContextMenu(); return false; };
document.onmouseup = document.onmousedown = function(event){
    if(event.which!==3) return;
    window.showContextMenu();
    return false;
}
window.showContextMenu = function(){
    alert('HERE SHOULD BE THE CONTEXT MENU');
};
```

More information on content scripts here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html